# How can I animate a list of vectors, which have entries either 1 or 0?

Tags: plotting, animation, listanimate

I have a list of vectors of equal length, that have entries either 1 or 0. I want to animate them vector by vector, essentially having one long string of the length of the vectors, which is black where the vector is 1 and white where the vector is 0. For the first frame the string is vector 1, for the second frame the string is vector 2,... for the n´th frame the string is vector n and so on.
Bonus points if this string is in a form of a circle.

If for example we deal with the following vectors:

```
{{1,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,0}}
```

Then the frames would essentialy look like this:

```
Frame1: MatrixPlot[{1,0,0,0,1}], Frame2: MatrixPlot[{0,1,0,0,1}], Frame3: MatrixPlot[{1,0,1,0,0}]
```

And if You want to try to do it around in the circle, just imagine the Frame1 would be wrapped around in a circle with an outer radius and an inner radius. And then Frame2 would be wrapped around in the same fashion. The image belows illustrates it:

!(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CXebkNj3l9U/hqdefault.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some test data:

```
bitWords = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {20, 5}]
```

Simple line case:

```
frames = ArrayPlot[{#}] & /@ bitWords;
ListAnimate[frames]
```

Circular case:

```
AnnulusForm[inner_, outer_][vector_List] :=
  With[ 
    {colors = GrayLevel /@ vector,
     segments = Annulus[{0, 0}, {inner, outer}, #] & /@ 
       Partition[Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/Length[vector]], 2, 1]},
    Thread[{colors, segments}]];
ListAnimate[Graphics@*AnnulusForm[4, 5] /@ bitWords]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
f2 = Map[PieChart[ConstantArray[1, Length @ #], 
     ChartStyle -> ReplaceAll[{0 -> White, 1 -> Black}] @ #, 
     SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}] &];
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1];

array = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {20, 10}];

ListAnimate @ f2 @ array
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
m={{1,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,0}};
ListAnimate[
  Table[(*of frames*)
    Graphics[
      Table[{(*of points*)
        If[m[[j,i]]==1,Black,Green],(*use Green instead of White to see the point*)
        PointSize[0.2],Point[{Cos[2 Pi i/Length[m[[1]]]],Sin[2 Pi i/Length[m[[1]]]]}]},
        {i,1,Length[m[[1]]]}]],
    {j,1,Length[m]}]]
```

Adjust point size as needed for your actual data